# Using VBA or Excel to compare four columns of data

Tags: excel, vba

I have one Excel worksheet with 4 columns of data. Column A and B show the name of the file and the page numbers and the data was retrieved awhile back. C and D show the name and pages but the data was retrieved this week and differs from the original. Some of the files now have more page numbers and some stayed the same. I want to find a way to either create an Excel formula or use VBA to give me the files where the page differs, so it would need to keep A and B together and then search C and D for the file name and see if the page numbers match up. There are over 9000 rows.

Answer (score 1):

```
 =if(index(D:D,match(A1,C:C,0))-B1=0,"match","no match")
```

**update**

Put the formula above into column E, after column A-D. So this column E will state by column A, whether column C's page number (col D) of equivalent filename is equal (match) column A's page number (col B) or no match. The indicator (E) refers to column A's filename - assuming column C is randomly sorted.

[image]

Comment: Even when your post, answers OP's question. Please provide not only a snippet that works. But explain what's happening, why it does what it should to etc.

Comment: sorry about that. updated with explanation.

Comment: no problem, now it's much better